# JQuery Autocomplete only when user inputs '@'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I couldn't find anywhere how to do this. I assumed that's pretty simple, but i'm not getting it!
I have a jquery autocomplete, and i only wants to complete when the user type '@' on the input, how can i do that? This is my actual code:

```
 $("#atualizacao").autocomplete({
        source: "<?= $this->baseUrl() ?>/ajax/completarmembro"
    });
```

I'm want something like

```
if (term.indexOf('@')>0){
   return true; //complete, show the complete
}else{
 //do nothing, dont load ajax, etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it.

```
$("#atualizacao").keydown(function(){
   if ($(this).val().indexOf('@') !== -1){
     $(this).autocomplete( "enable" );
   }else{
     $(this).autocomplete( "disable" );
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't working, but i founded that it can't be 'indexOf('@') > 0', it has to be 'indexOf('@') !== -1', now it's working fine ;)

Comment: @wiLLiamcastrO oh and `keyup` instead of `keydown` may work better for you.